# Using browserify for node.js request package

Tags: javascript, browserify

I want to browserify a very simple example with using the node.js request package. Here the `http.test.js` file:

```
var request = require('request');

function getDataFromService() {
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); 
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log('body:', body);
    });
}
```

Then I run browserify as follows:

`browserify http.test.js -o bundle.js`

The `index.html` looks like

```
<html>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        getDataFromService();
    </script>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running `index.html` in my browser I get the following error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: getDataFromService is not defined*

So, what's wrong with it?

Comment: If browserfy is like webpack, then it won't pollute the global automatically.  You normally have to define externals etc.  Alternatively why not just call getDataFromService from within your source code, then when bundle.js is included it will automatically call it.

Comment: @artgb: It is 2,1 MB large ;)

Comment: I think getDataFromService became local function of a function not global